# Seekbar crashes due to String format

Tags: java, android, seekbar, changelistener

The SeekBar on my tip calculator app crashes when I enter %**0**.02f as a parameter in the format method.

```
tipAmountEditText.setText(String.format("%0.02f", tipAmount));
```

I fixed this problem by removing the integer part thus becoming just `%.02f`. The only feature I can say about this issue is that it popped up using a ChangeListener. I do not understand why this would be an issue and I hope someone could enlighten me. If you need see the bigger picture, my code in its entirety is on my github: https://github.com/xamroc/TipCalc

```
private OnSeekBarChangeListener tipSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {

        tipAmount = (tipSeekBar.getProgress()) * .01;

        tipAmountEditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", tipAmount));

        updateTipAndFinalBill();

    }

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `String.format("%0.02f", tipAmount)`  you are getting

```
java.util.MissingFormatWidthException

//This Unchecked exception thrown when the format width is required.
```

[Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/MissingFormatWidthException.html)

***Reason:***

```
%0.02f interprets as a floating point at least 0 wide.

Thats why it gives MissingFormatWidthException // as its assuming width to 0
```

*So use Following Instead*

```
String.format("%.02f", tipAmount)
```

Comment: May I know what the purpose of ``#`` is? Also, how is the zero causing the crash? Is it a parameter format issue?